# When does DBwn update buffers in Database buffer cache to database disk?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning some basic knowledge about Oracle Database Architecture, and there are two examples.

1. The steps involved in executing a data manipulation language (DML) statements.
2. The steps involved in executing COMMIT command.

[Executing DML steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOhby.png)

The steps are as follows:

> 1. The server process receives the statement and checks the library cache for any shared SQL area that contains a similar SQL statement.
>      If a shared SQL area is found, the server process checks the user’s
>      access privileges for the requested data, and the existing shared SQL
>      area is used to process the statement. If not, a new shared SQL area
>      is allocated for the statement, so that it can be parsed and
>      processed.
> 2. If the data and undo segment blocks are not already in the buffer cache, the server process reads them from the data files into the
>      buffer cache. The server process locks the rows that are to be
>      modified.
> 3. The server process records the changes to be made to the data buffers as well as the undo changes. These changes are written to the
>      redo log buffer before the in-memory data and undo buffers are
>      modified. This is called write-ahead logging.
> 4. The undo segment buffers contain values of the data before it is modified. The undo buffers are used to store the before image of the
>      data so that the DML statements can be rolled back, if necessary. The
>      data buffers record the new values of the data.
> 5. The user gets feedback from the DML operation (such as how many rows were affected by the operation).

[COMMIT Process steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAMjV.png)

The steps are as follows:

> 1. The server process places a commit record, along with the system change number (SCN), in the redo log buffer. The SCN is monotonically
>      incremented and is unique within the database.
> 2. The LGWR background process performs a contiguous write of all the redo log buffer entries up to and including the commit record to the
>      redo log files.
> 3. If modified blocks are still in the SGA, and if no other session is modifying them, then the database removes lock-related transaction
>      information from the blocks.
> 4. The server process provides feedback to the user process about the completion of the transaction.

First question: Do server process or background process finally move or migrate Redo log files to Data files? If yes, how to do this process?

Thanks to Nicholas Krasnov & JSapkota comments. There doesn't exist this kind of "Migration" process because they serve different purposes. Data files are the data of the database and Redo log files are used to recover the database. DBWn is responsible for writing data to data files and LGWR write redo log buffer to the active redo log file on disk.

My Second question: When does DBwn(Database writer process) modify buffers in the cache to database disk? Update database disk before COMMIT or after COMMIT.

Comment: No they don't, LGWR(Log Writer Background Process) writes Redo Logs(only change vectors) to Red Log Files from Redo Log Buffer. DBWR(Database Writer Process) writes the dirty buffer(modified blocks on buffer cache, actual data) to data files.

Comment: `move or migrate Redo log files to Data files?` Data files and Redo log files ate two absolutely different types of files. The one never "migrates" to  the other. They are there to server different purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DBwn** will dose not write to database files because of issuing `commit` statement. `Commit` just means that this is a end of transaction. Locks on table or rows are released, SCN is incremented, and `LGWR` writes the SCN and changes to online redolog file.

The database buffer cache has two list

```
1) Write list
2) least-recently-used (LRU) list
```

Least-recently-used (LRU) list has dirty buffer. Dirty buffer is those buffers which were modified. Commit will indirectly make a buffer dirty. It will be in buffer as its been recently accessed.

`DBwn` neither writes in the datafile before the commit nor after. It has its own scenarios like when checkpoint happens or dirty buffers reaches threshold or there is no free buffer etc.

I hope, I answered your question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks,based on your answer, i found more detailed information on this site: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/memory.htm#i10221